# Copy URL button vulnerability

Tags: javascript, wordpress, apache

I have a website where I do some daily posts. To make sharing the link easier, I created a Copy URL button along with the social media sharing buttons.

The user accesses the site, clicks the button and the url is automatically copied. The user just has to paste wherever he wants.

On my website I have enabled almost all CSP security policies. I left all of them restricted to the site itself. I do not carry external codes.

Even with all this configuration, is there any vulnerability, security breach both on the site side and on the client side when using the Copy URL button?

If you have a vulnerability, is there a way to protect yourself and the customer without having to disable the Copy URL button?